# Add a column to a data frame based on percentiles calculated by group

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame with the following form

```
Group    Value
  A       0.20
  A       0.86
  A       1.42
  A       0.35
  B       1.77
  B       0.56
  B       0.21
  .        .
  .        .
```

I want to add a column `Alert` that takes two possible values:

- '1' if `Value` for a particular `Group` either exceeds the `1 - thr` percentile or is less than the `thr` percentile of `Value` for each particular `Group`, where `thr` is a user-defined threshold
- '0' otherwise.

For example, say that the `1 - thr` and `thr` percentiles for `Value` in `Group` A are 1.0 and 0.25; the corresponding values of the new column (let's call it `Alert`) would be

```
    Group    Value   Alert
      A       0.20     1
      A       0.86     0
      A       1.42     1
      A       0.35     0
```

I have tried the following

```
def make_alert(x, thr):
if x >= np.percentile(x, 1 - thr) | x <= np.percentile(x, thr):
    return 0
else:
    return 1 

pdf.groupby('Name').apply(lambda x: make_alert(x['Value'], AlertThr))
```

However this is not working as my function is applied to every element of the corresponding column, and therefore the upper and lower thresholds for each group are not being calculated.

Could someone please provide a hint as to how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think....(new to this myself)
that the use of `.apply` means the function is applied to the contents of the 'Name' column. Instead consider...

```
df['Alert'] = df['Value'].apply(your_function)
```

Comment: So in this case you make a new column `['Alert']` which has the value of the `['Value']` column after applying your `make_alert` function. Though I'm not necessarily sure how you pass two arguments to your function as I've only ever used `.apply` to pass just the contents of the cell. Maybe check the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

Comment: If I do `pdf.groupby('Group').quantile([thr, 1 - thr])` I get a table with the upper and lower decision boundaries for each `Group`, what I can't see is then how I use the values in this table to compute the alerts I need.